# I want to change the school year every year starting when it's march

Tags: c#

I want to change the school year every march of a year. But my codes looks so wrong that it will only execute when the month will turn march.

```
String month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
if(month == "March"){

string yearBegin = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
int yearEnd = int.Parse(yearEnd)+1;
SchoolYear.Text = "S.Y."+yearBegin+"-"+yearEnd;}
```

Comment: You do not have to convert to string using a particular format to determine the month.  `DateTime.Month` tells you the month and as an integer it wont break depending on the language

Comment: It only shows DateTime.DaysInMonth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assume that these are the rules of the School Year

- From March to December it will be {current year}-{next year}
- January and February will be {last year}-{current year}

So your code would be:

```
//School Year changes in March until next March
int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
if (month >= 3)//from March to December it will be {current year}-{next year}
{
    int yearBegin = DateTime.Now.Year;
}
else //January and February will be {last year}-{current year}
{
    int yearBegin = DateTime.Now.Year - 1;
}

int yearEnd = yearBegin + 1;
SchoolYear.Text = "S.Y." + yearBegin + "-" + yearEnd;
```

And if you want to have the less code as possible you could just write

```
int yearBegin = DateTime.Now.Month >= 3 ? DateTime.Now.Year : DateTime.Now.Year - 1;
SchoolYear.Text = $"S.Y.{yearBegin}-{yearBegin + 1}";
```

Comment: no problem, glad to help! did it work? if so, please accept the answer it helped you the most. Cheers.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing too much string work, just work with the `DateTime` object -

```
var today = DateTime.Now;

//if March
if(today.Month == 3)
{
    SchoolYear.Text = $"S.Y.{today.Year}-{today.AddYears(1).Year}";
}
```

Comment: @JQSOFT yep i fat fingered it.  Fixed

Comment: Thankyou . It hepled